# Union Firebase Analytics Data in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I've got Firebase Analytics linked to Big Query for us to query event data from a mobile app but I've noticed that it creates a new table each for each days events. Which means I need to union the tables if I want to see multiple days worth of data. The main issue is that I need to update the query every day so that it includes the new days events which while being arduous will mean the query will eventually become a bit ridiculous because I'm currently listing all of the columns I care about rather than a `SELECT *`.

Is there a way to setup Big Query to automatically union the tables as they are created or to just have 1 table which has all the data appended to it?

Comment: take a look at [Wildcard tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/wildcard-table-reference). this is the way to go for you

Comment: Wow as it turns it out it was a simple as adding the asterisk inlace of the table suffix. Thanks Mikhail 